# Best practice for using Auth0 in android app

Tags: android, kotlin, auth0

I have an app that has a single activity that has a sign in fragment followed by the actual fragments of the app. What is the best practice to pass user tokens (access token, id token and so on) to the other fragments?

I see that Auth0 has a SecureCredentialManager, but I don't really see what the intention is when it comes to accessing the tokens from other fragments and their code examples are not really doing this.

Any advise here?

Comment: Who's your threat you're looking to protect yourself from?  The user?  A malicious program on the device?  An outside attacker? Generally you just write that info into a global, and persist to disk if needed.  That's sufficient for most apps, but yours may need to be more protected.

Comment: That is also what the SecureCredentialManager does - saving to SharedPreferences. But I donøt see how to access the values again through the SecureCredentialsManager from another fragment.